# How to select context menu items without keyboard input in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, contextmenu, selenium-webdriver, right-click

I am able to select the context menu item by providing keyboard input. i just wanted to know whether there is any way to select a context menu item without keyboard input in Selenium WebDriver.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By 'without keyboard input' do you mean physical input? Is it okay if Selenium is simulating these key presses for you?

Comment: @ Nashibukasan - i am able to simulate key presses using selenium. i want to know if there is some other way to select context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the ContextMenu displayed via Selenium, you can then use `SendKeys` to send **down** key presses until the correct option is selected followed by an **enter** key. If this isn't working as separate calls try and perform the ContextMenu and all the key presses sequentially using the `Action` class (eg. build the action sequence and then `perform()` them).

A list of Java Selenium Key Enums can be found [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html).

Comment: down key and enter key are keyboard inputs, my question is whether there is a way to select context menu item without using keyboard inputs

Comment: My understand is that context menus can have different options in different situations and are specific to browsers, therefore, it would be difficult to perform these actions through Selenium. Also, using sendkeys is a viable option so I doubt Selenium are likely to work on this.